# SharePoint- add web part zone in div via edit source

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have three web parts as content editor on page on SharePoint site. Each content editor is split into content div and image div which I added code using option "Edit Source". In following divs I want to add web part zone using code or in edit source opt, if is possibility there? so that in left div i can allow user to add code and in left one image! I am using SharePoint -2013 online.

```
<div class="MyWrapper_01" style="width: 100%;"> 
  <div id="MyContent_01" style="float: left; width: 63%; background-color: red;"> content... </div> 
  <div id="MyContentImageRight_01" style="float: right; width: 35%; background-color: blue;"> image... </div> 
</div>
```

[image]

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot add webpart zones using the content editor webpart, as the webpart zones are server side controls. Only way to achieve this is by editing page layouts.